# lv2 and lv2-dev libraries or equivalent

Tags: ubuntu-studio, ardour

I'm compiling ardour3 from source and as far as I can tell I have all the libraries mentioned in http://ardour.org/building_ardour3

Unfortunately running ./waf configure gives the following error

```
Checking for 'lv2' >= 1.0.0                          : not found
```

I have the following packages installed that look useful but don't seem to help:

```
i   lv2-c++-tools                   - library and tools for LV2 plugins         
i   lv2-extensions-good             - LV2 extensions from the "good" set        
i A lv2core                         - LV2 audio plugin specification            
i   lv2fil                          - Stereo and mono LV2 plugins, four-band par
i   lv2file                         - Command-line program to apply LV2 effects 
i   lv2proc                         - command line effect processor             
i   lv2vocoder                      - LV2 vocoder plugin
```

Where can I find that library. I'm okay with compiling it myself.

Apparently there is a package in SID: http://packages.debian.org/sid/lv2-dev I'll try getting that in a while

The source code can be had via subversion:

`svn co http://subversion.ardour.org/svn/ardour2/branches/3.0`

Comment: Nate: please see edited answer for a working solution. It appears ardour wants the latest versions which must be built from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ardour wants the latest *unified* version of *lv2*, which was only released on April 18, 2012, and is not available in any repositories yet. You must download and build it from source:

1. Download http://lv2plug.in/spec/lv2-1.0.0.tar.bz2, extract and enter source directory.
2. `./waf configure && ./waf build && sudo ./waf install` should do the trick.

*waf* for Ardour will then also ask you for the latest versions of the following dependencies, which you can download from the below URLs and build/install as above.
Note that the *drobilla.net* server is sometimes offline, in which case just google the filenames and you will get alternative download servers.

1. http://download.drobilla.net/serd-0.14.0.tar.bz2
2. http://download.drobilla.net/sord-0.8.0.tar.bz2
3. http://download.drobilla.net/sratom-0.2.0.tar.bz2
4. http://download.drobilla.net/lilv-0.14.2.tar.bz2
5. http://download.drobilla.net/suil-0.6.4.tar.bz2

Comment: I already had all of these installed except lv2proc. Adding it didn't improve the situation. I'm editing my original post to contain this info.

Comment: @NateIverson: please post a *direct* link to the source.

Comment: @ I got the link through subversion I'll edit it into the original post